# Back to Top Link, Dynamically Created, with Scroll

Tags: jquery-plugins, dynamic, scroll, hyperlink

**SUMMARY:**

I need to insert a "Back to Top" links after every <div class="wrapSection">.  I've been successful using the following:

```
<script>
$('.wrapSection').after('
    <div class="backToTop clearfix">
       <a href="#top" class="up">Back To Top </a>
    </div>
 ');
</script>
```

However, I want to use a smooth scroll when clicking 'Back to Top.'  With that in mind, I tried the following:

```
<script>
$('.wrapSection').after('
<div class="backToTop clearfix">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('top')" class="up">
      Back To Top
    </a>
</div>
');
</script>
```

That does not work.  Being a jQuery rookie, I did what seemed logical, which seems to never be  the correct answer.

**IN A NUTSHELL**

More or less, I need this to appear, dynamically, after every <div class="wrapSection">:

```
<div class="backToTop">
    <a class="top" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="goToByScroll('top')">
        Back to Top
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I know last-item.js is pretty messy, but it's working for the most part

Comment: Looking at the script `backtotop.js`, there seems to be a foreign character at the end which is preventing the browser from running it.

Comment: I copied it directly from below, let me try the jsfiddle page code.

Comment: OK, still no go, copied from below and jsfiddle with no luck

Comment: What about Dropbox or your editor? If I view the file in Chrome, it shows this: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/41938/2012-12-23_224328.png

If you're using Chrome, open the console when viewing the page and paste the main JS code straight in to it and hit Enter. For me, it executes fine with the intended results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    // Markup to add each time - just give the element a class to attach an event to
    var top_html = '<div class="backToTop"><a href="#" class="top">Back To Top</a></div>';
    $(".wrapSection").after(top_html);

    // Use event delegation (see http://api.jquery.com/on/)
    $("body").on("click", ".top", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    });
});​
```

You can try a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/F9pDw/

Comment: Craig, your solution ended up working.  I will keep this example here for a while, but the jsfiddle link is the best example for anyone who comes along.